# Libcurl to send audio file

Tags: audio, file-upload, libcurl

I am trying to send a wav file to my ruby server using libcurl. It is a multi-form post, here's the main snippet of code:

```
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "192.168.0.136:3000/upload");

        struct curl_httppost *post = NULL;
        struct curl_httppost *last = NULL;

        //Added longer timeout in case of large files
        //Two forms, one for file and another for data
        curl_formadd(&post, &last, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "file", CURLFORM_FILECONTENT, "log1.wav", CURLFORM_END);
        curl_formadd(&post, &last, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "data", CURLFORM_PTRCONTENTS, data, CURLFORM_END);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, post);

       curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
       curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&respons_buf);
       res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

I receive the file as a encoded text, that I am not sure what to do with. This is the same method I sent text files. Am I missing some header information?

Answer (score 0):

libcurl doesn't encode or transform the data in any way when it sends a multipart form post. It sends the exact bytes it read from the file on your disk.

If you don't receive the exact same data in the server end, the server software probably performed some magic tricks on it for you. Possibly based on the non-existing Content-Type: header in that particular section of the post. You could try adding `CURLFORM_CONTENTTYPE` and the type for the file.